# creating a command to go to a specific shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

So basically, I just installed ubuntu on bash on my windows PC and every time I have to go to desktop I have to type cd /mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop. is there a way that I can make a script or command so everytime i type in "desktop" it changes my directory to desktop? I've never done Linux/bash scripting and therefore I have no clue. I just use it for the g++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this:

1. Create an executable program that runs the command `cd /mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop` (this is iain's answer, and a perfectly fine one; the only issue might be that you'll need to either enter the full path for that program every time you run it, or you'll need to put it into a directory that is already included in your `$PATH` environment variable.)
2. Create an environment variable that contains the path you'd like, then cd to it `cd $DESKTOP`.

   ```
   export DESKTOP="/mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop"
   cd $DESKTOP
   ```

   You'll likely want to put the creation of this environment variable into your .bashrc or .profile, so it gets created each time you login.

   ```
   echo 'export DESKTOP="/mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop"' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

   (Note: the above adds it to the end of the .bashrc file. Once you learn more about bash and .bashrc you will probably want to move it to another location in the file.)
3. Create an alias that does the same thing.

   ```
   alias mydesk='cd /mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop'
   ```

   Again, you'll likely want to add the creation of this alias to your .bashrc or .profile file, so it gets created each time you login:

   ```
   echo "alias mydesk='cd /mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop'" >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

   (Note: the above adds it to the end of the .bashrc file. Once you learn more about bash and .bashrc you will probably want to move it to another location in the file or even a different file completely.)
4. Assuming that "/mnt/c/Users/Name/" is your home directory, you can just use the shortcut for that, then append "Desktop" to it:

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop
   ```

   or

   ```
   cd $HOME/Desktop
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try ...

make a file called desktop

Put this into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop
```

close the file and then make it executable.

```
$ chmod +x desktop
```

Now by typing `. desktop` (note the dot) you should be taken to your desktop.

You may also be able to add the script to your path, so that it will run from anywhere in the bash environment; Depending upon how like ubuntu your environment is.